# Bootstrap row that goes to two columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've a problem with bootstrap.

I have a row with 4 elements that in a large browser are in a row with 4 25% columns.
I would like to use a structure with 2 rows and 2 columns when the browser is a Bootstrap XS o SM, is it possible without upsetting the structure?

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 padding-h-sm line-height-sm">
        <div class="icon"><img src="images/mondiali-pallavolo/comunicare.png"></div>
        <div>Comunicare news e aggiornamenti sul mondiale femminile.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 padding-h-sm line-height-sm">
        <div class="icon"><img src="images/mondiali-pallavolo/responsive.png"></div>
        <div>Rendere fruibili i contenuti in qualsiasi momento.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 padding-h-sm line-height-sm">
        <div class="icon"><img src="images/mondiali-pallavolo/gestione.png"></div>
        <div>Semplificare la creazione e la gestione dei contenuti.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 padding-h-sm line-height-sm">
        <div class="icon"><img src="images/mondiali-pallavolo/sponsor.png"></div>
        <div>Aumentare la visibilità degli sponsor così da sostenere l'investimento.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it working as you want now? http://www.bootply.com/IX8dftfhsS

Comment: Yes, sorry, the problem is that with the different width of text they are not aligned.
Image: https://imageshack.com/i/ez0d6966j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it's the variable length of the text that causes this, but variable height images would do the same. The best fix is the `hidden-* clearfix` combo trick... put it after your 2nd column, and it will `clearfix` on non-`lg` devices only, but leaving as-is on `lg`, like so:

```
<div class="hidden-lg clearfix"></div>
```

**Example: http://www.bootply.com/emnE5Yaoil**

Comment: `!=lg` is a tad more accurate than `<lg`, as it's analogously correct for other screen sizes like `sm` etc.

Comment: yeah, you're right. worse yet, it seems you have to explicitly state which col's to hide, yet when designating a device, it assumes "and up". don't understand why hidden doesn't work the same way

Answer (score 0):

It's going to two columns per row because you are telling it to do that with col-xs-6. If you want it to always be a four column per row layout, you want to do this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 padding-h-sm line-height-sm">
        <div class="icon"><img src="images/mondiali-pallavolo/comunicare.png"></div>
        <div>Comunicare news e aggiornamenti sul mondiale femminile.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 padding-h-sm line-height-sm">
        <div class="icon"><img src="images/mondiali-pallavolo/responsive.png"></div>
        <div>Rendere fruibili i contenuti in qualsiasi momento.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 padding-h-sm line-height-sm">
        <div class="icon"><img src="images/mondiali-pallavolo/gestione.png"></div>
        <div>Semplificare la creazione e la gestione dei contenuti.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 padding-h-sm line-height-sm">
        <div class="icon"><img src="images/mondiali-pallavolo/sponsor.png"></div>
        <div>Aumentare la visibilità degli sponsor così da sostenere l'investimento.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No man, sorry probably I have not explained the problem correctly.
I want col-md-3 and col-xs-6 but I also want that on a small browser they are aligned, and not like that:https://imageshack.com/i/ez0d6966j

Comment: I see. It looks like your problem is likely the height of the the div is not jiving.  If you set a height on the images, everything will likely fall back inline.

Comment: Mmm thanks, correct :)
Can I ask you how can I set every DIV to a standard height (that is the same height of the heightest div in the row)?
The other method is surely to put every div with a prefixed static height, buy i think is not optimized.

Comment: Personally, I would edit the images so they are all the same size. If you don't want to go that route, you could also set a percentage-based height and width on div.icon and then add the img-responsive class to your images.  Both ways should help.